# Powershell - Open URL and login

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run a Powershell script that opens a website in a default browser, sets username and password input values, and then triggers a button click event?
Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: Can't you make a REST request to the API instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can use [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) on a string containing a URL to open the default Web browser. And you can use [SendKeys](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/) to send keystrokes to an application.

If you want to automate a Web browser, you can try [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

If you want to manage logons among users, you can try [RoboForm](https://www.roboform.com/business).

If you want to wrap a line-of-business application for single sign-on, you can try [Azure AD Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-application-proxy).

My advice is to avoid public macros because they are unreliable and generate help desk requests.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike! This is very useful.